# How to convert mongodb date object in "mm/dd/yyyy" format in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I am using jquery Date picker in "mm/dd/yyyy" format and saving it to mongodb default Date Type. Now the problem is when i fetch the all documents from db the date looks like "2015-08-29T18:30:00.000Z". I want to convert this to mm/dd/yyyy format so that i can display this in my date field while editing this record.

Below is my code:
Before returning the document, i want to chnage the dates in "mm/dd/yyy" format.

```
var query = Trips.findOne({"_id":tripId},function (err, trip) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        console.log(trip.tripEndDate);           
        res.json(trip);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) is what you need.

```
d = new Date()
> Sun Aug 30 2015 22:47:48 GMT+0300 (MSK)
d.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
> "8/30/2015"
```

Comment: But when I try to modify the object nothing gets changed, beacauae I think the data type of the object is date and I am trying to convert it to a string

Comment: Well, build a new object and push _that_ to your datepicker.

Comment: How can I do this in reverse? If I have a stirng 8/30/2015 how do I convert it to a date so I can compare it